# What is the command to summon the biggest slime in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon the biggest slime but I forgot how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! :) Before asking a question here, you should research to see if you can find an answer on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure cheats are enabled, and type this command:

```
/summon Slime x y z {Size:size}
```

`x`, `y`, and `z` are the coordinates where you want to spawn the slime. This is optional (if left blank, the slime will spawn at the position of the player). `size` is the size of the slime.

Examples:

```
/summon Slime {Size:50}             spawns a slime of size 50 at your position
/summon Slime 2 10 -224 {Size:1}    spawns a slime of size 1 at the point (2, 10, -224)
```

Comment: But what is the biggest slime?  I would assume it's 2147483647...

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt According to the comments on [PlanetMinecraft](http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/how-to-summon-giant-slime-lag-your-computer/), the maximum size is 127. I'm not sure if that's correct or not, but I imagine anything bigger than that would be too large for the game to render.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest slime you may spawn is of Size:256. You may check [the page on Slimes][1] if this is true or not. So, if you want to summon the Slime at it's largest size, you would type:

```
/summon Slime x y z Size:256
```

If I'm not wrong.
[1]: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime

Comment: The `Size:` tag is 0-255 rather than 1-256, where 0 is a slime of size 1, and 255 is a slime of size 256.